# Error passing headers to Invoke-RestMethod

Tags: powershell, rest, graph, oauth-2.0

I have one function that obtains an OAuth 2 token and assembles a header; and others that use the header to make various requests to Microsoft Graph.

The function that assembles the header has two methods: one is interactive with a device code flow; and the other is non-interactive with a username and password flow.
Both methods produce a header that looks the same. The token object and the header object are the same types of object in both cases.

But, when the header is used in another GET function, the function fails in the interactive case and succeeds in the non-interactive case. The error is: "Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.Collections.IDictionary' required by parameter 'Headers'."

The object returned by the header function is an array (object, base type: system array) in the failed case. It is a hashtable (hashtable, base type: system object) in the successful case. Even though, internally in the function, the token and the header are the same type. Token is System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject, and header is hashtable.

The code that assembles the header is: `$authHeader = @{
            'Authorization' = "Bearer $( $tokenResponse.access_token)"
            'Content-Type'  = "application/json"
            'ExpiresOn'     = $( $tokenResponse.expires_in)`

The access tokens are both long strings contained in the token response. They seem similar, and both decode OK at jwt.io.

Any ideas why two headers that look the same would be different object types, and how to get the failed one into an IDictionary format?

Comment: I have found the source of the problem. In the interactive authentication, an extra string is being inserted into the header when I pass it out of the function.
The header being returned in the function looks like this: ```{
    "Authorization":  "Bearer xyzabc }```
The header received by the expression calling the function is like this

Comment: The header received by the expression calling the function is like this

```[
    "",
    {
        "Authorization":  "Bearer xyzabc
}
]```

Next stop is to find out why.

Comment: Now I know the reason, and I can write the most horrible kludge to fix it:

```$t = $Header.GetType().FullName

    if ($t = "System.Object[]") {
        $Header = $Header[1]
    }```

This actually works. But it is horribly ugly. There must be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. A prompt for input in the interactive authentication added an empty string to the output. Solution was to add `| Out-Null` to the prompt.